# How can I access the Heroku Postgres Database copy?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I was one of the users who had their free DB deleted. I notice they left me with a DB copy when I run `heroku pg:backups` as you can see below:

```
(venv) MacBook-Pro-4:TheDropCore adamlamorre$ heroku pg:backups
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.60.2 to 8.0.1.
=== Backups
No backups. Capture one with heroku pg:backups:capture

=== Restores
No restores found. Use heroku pg:backups:restore to restore a backup

=== Copies
ID    Started at                 Status                               Size      From       To
────  ─────────────────────────  ───────────────────────────────────  ────────  ─────────  ───────────
c001  2021-11-22 02:49:15 +0000  Completed 2021-11-22 02:49:33 +0000  120.00KB  From Name  Target Name
```

How do I access `c001` and apply it to a new DB?